# .NET core Auth cookie sharing

Tags: .net, .net-core, authorization

I have SSO implementation to implement and I have 2 applications in which share auth cookie.

This is the code of ConfigureServices method from first application (the login form application):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Tylde\Progetti\_commonCookies"))
            .SetApplicationName("NAU");

        services.AddAuthentication("AuthCookie")
            .AddCookie("AuthCookie", config =>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "User.Cookie";
                config.LoginPath = "/Authentication/SignIn";
            });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    }
```

This is the code of ConfigureServices method from the second one:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Tylde\Progetti\_commonCookies"))
            .SetApplicationName("NAU");

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

Applications are now configured in local IIS and the urls are:

http://localhost:8081/Authentication/SignIn
and
http://localhost:8082/Home

Can anybody help me, please?

Thank and sorry for my english!

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Do you have it working in at least one application?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your option to share cookies across multiple domains, you can perform the following steps

1. Define the domains for the 2 applications like `app1.product.com` and `app2.product.com`
2. You could setup the local machine's hosts file to point. the hosts file is normally found in the following paths (Windos OS: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` or Linux OS: `/etc/hosts`)

> 127.0.0.1 to app1.product.com app2.product.com

3. When you browse your application you can use the above fake domain so that you can have the cookie domain setup and test it out with the local environment also.

The assumption made is that you have a custom authentication, however when you are preferring to use any authorization server with Bearer tokens, it is better to handle the validations at the middleware level with the tokens so that you don't depend on the cookies as cookies are not very secure, In case you prefer to use cookie-only SSO, please set your cookie's http property to be true.

HTH

Comment: Thank...I will try this but I would prefer a programnmatic solution, if exists.